# fontspec and makecmds.sty, re: polyglossia

Tags: fontspec

Can someone explain to me in layman's terms what fontspec is? And is it needed by polyglossia?

Thanks

Bonus points: "makecmds.sty not found". Why?

Comment: it is best not to ask unrelated questions in the same post, makecmds you presumably just need to install if you don't have it `tlmgr install makecmds` (or equivalent in miktex)  although xparse is possibly recommended instead these days.  describing fontspec will take a longer answer

Comment: The Getting started section of the fontspec manual is fairly easy reading (`texdoc fontspec` or online copy at http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf

Comment: Thanks guys, and sorry for any improprieties; I just don't know where else to look for answers. Re makecmds, on running `tlmgr install makecmds`, I get problems with tlpdb.

Comment: If you have a tlmgr failure then you should ask a new question about that, showing the full error message that you get, that us unrelated to a fontspec/polyglossia question.